# How to fetch data from mongodB in Scala

Tags: mongodb, scala

I wrote following code to fetch data from MongoDB

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import org.mongodb.scala.{ Document, MongoClient, MongoCollection, MongoDatabase }

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

object MongoService extends Service {
  val conf = ConfigFactory.load()
  implicit val mongoService: MongoClient = MongoClient(conf.getString("mongo.url"))
  implicit val mongoDB: MongoDatabase = mongoService.getDatabase(conf.getString("mongo.db"))
  implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.global

  def getAllDocumentsFromCollection(collection: String) = {
    mongoDB.getCollection(collection).find()
  }
}
```

But when I tried to get data from `getAllDocumentsFromCollection` I'm not getting each data for further manipulation. Instead I'm getting

```
FindObservable(com.mongodb.async.client.FindIterableImpl@23555cf5)
```

UPDATED:

```
object MongoService {
  // My settings (see available connection options)
  val mongoUri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/smsto?authMode=scram-sha1"

  import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global // use any appropriate context

  // Connect to the database: Must be done only once per application
  val driver = MongoDriver()
  val parsedUri = MongoConnection.parseURI(mongoUri)
  val connection = parsedUri.map(driver.connection(_))

  // Database and collections: Get references
  val futureConnection = Future.fromTry(connection)
  def db1: Future[DefaultDB] = futureConnection.flatMap(_.database("smsto"))
  def personCollection = db1.map(_.collection("person"))

  // Write Documents: insert or update

  implicit def personWriter: BSONDocumentWriter[Person] = Macros.writer[Person]
  // or provide a custom one

  def createPerson(person: Person): Future[Unit] =
        personCollection.flatMap(_.insert(person).map(_ => {})) // use personWriter
  def getAll(collection: String) =
    db1.map(_.collection(collection))

  // Custom persistent types
  case class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int)
}
```

I tried to use reactivemongo as well with above code but I couldn't make it work for `getAll` and getting following error in `createPerson`
[image]
Please suggest how can I get all data from a collection.

Comment: Did you read the [**documentation**](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.5/getting-started/quick-tour-primer/) - tl;dr the mongo Scala driver is built over the java async driver, that means thar every operation over the db will be executed asynchronously _(meaning you won't get the results but instead an abstraction to work on them with callbacks)_. You may write your own observable, or just call the `toFuture` method to get a **Future[Iterable[Document]]** and operate over it, or if you really want your documents "right now" and make your code completely synchronous await the future

Comment: Or have a look at http://reactivemongo.org/ (I'm maintainer of)

Comment: @cchantep I've tried with reactivemongo. I've updated my question. Please kindly check above. I couldn't make it work :(

Comment: "I couldn't make it work for getAll" is not sufficiently specific to get helped, error? BTW the get all is not doing any query, so cannot return any result: http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/documentation/tutorial/find-documents.html

Comment: @cchantep I've updated question with error on `createPerson`.

Comment: rather check whether it's compile in SBT, IDE can be not really good with dependent types

Comment: Received `Cannot use Netty KQueue
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: reactivemongo.io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueSocketChannel
` and `Cannot use Netty EPoll
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: reactivemongo.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollSocketChannel
`

Answer (score 3):

This is likely too late for the OP, but hopefully the following methods of retrieving & iterating over collections using mongo-spark can prove useful to others.

**The Asynchronous Way** - Iterating over documents asynchronously means you won't have to store an entire collection in-memory, which can become unreasonable for large collections. However, you won't have access to all your documents outside the `subscribe` code block for reuse. I'd recommend doing things asynchronously if you can, since this is how the mongo-scala driver was intended to be used.

```
db.getCollection(collectionName).find().subscribe(
    (doc: org.mongodb.scala.bson.Document) => {
        // operate on an individual document here
    },
    (e: Throwable) => {
        // do something with errors here, if desired
    },
    () => {
        // this signifies that you've reached the end of your collection
    }
)
```

**The "Synchronous" Way** - This is a pattern I use when my use-case calls for a synchronous solution, and I'm working with smaller collections or result-sets. It still uses the asynchronous mongo-scala driver, but it returns a list of documents and blocks downstream code execution until all documents are returned. Handling errors and timeouts may depend on your use case.

```
import org.mongodb.scala._
import org.mongodb.scala.bson.Document
import org.mongodb.scala.model.Filters
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

/* This function optionally takes filters if you do not wish to return the entire collection.
 * You could extend it to take other optional query params, such as org.mongodb.scala.model.{Sorts, Projections, Aggregates}
 */
def getDocsSync(db: MongoDatabase, collectionName: String, filters: Option[conversions.Bson]): ListBuffer[Document] = {
    val docs = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Document]()
    var processing = true
    val query = if (filters.isDefined) {
        db.getCollection(collectionName).find(filters.get)
    } else {
        db.getCollection(collectionName).find()
    }
    query.subscribe(
        (doc: Document) => docs.append(doc), // add doc to mutable list
        (e: Throwable) => throw e,
        () => processing = false
    )
    while (processing) {
        Thread.sleep(100) // wait here until all docs have been returned
    }
    docs
}
```

```
// sample usage of 'synchronous' method
val client: MongoClient = MongoClient(uriString)
val db: MongoDatabase = client.getDatabase(dbName)
val allDocs = getDocsSync(db, "myCollection", Option.empty)
val someDocs = getDocsSync(db, "myCollection", Option(Filters.eq("fieldName", "foo")))
```